# How to pass state between renderCell components in Material UI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

How can I change the `MenuItems` of one `Select` when another `Select` component changes using `DataGrid`? I need to be able to pass the state of one `Select` component to the other, but I'm not sure how when using `renderCell`.

For example, let's say I have the following object:

```
const data = {
  "/path/to/file1.csv": {
    parameters: ["Parameter 1", "Parameter 2", "Parameter 3"],
  },
  "/path/to/file2.csv": {
    parameters: ["Parameter 2", "Parameter 3", "Parameter 4"],
  },
  "/path/to/file3.csv": {
    parameters: ["Parameter 5", "Parameter 6", "Parameter 7"],
  },
};
```

In my `DataGrid` table, every time I add a new row with the click of a button, the first cell has a `Select` component containing `Object.keys(data)`.

The second cell contains another `Select` component. I want this `Select` component to contain parameters that are dependent on the value selected. For example, if `/path/to/file1.csv` is selected, I want to make available those parameters (`Parameter 1, Parameter 2, Parameter 3`), but if `/path/to/file3.csv` is selected, I want to make available those parameters (`Parameter 5, Parameter 6, Parameter 7`).

Here's my component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Button, Select, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Delete";
import { DataGrid, GridActionsCellItem } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const FileSelect = (props) => {
  const { value } = props;
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Select id="file-select" value={file} onChange={handleChange} fullWidth>
      {value?.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={item}>
          {item}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};

FileSelect.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.array,
};

const ParameterSelect = (props) => {
  const { value } = props;
  const [parameter, setParameter] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setParameter(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      id="parameter-select"
      value={parameter}
      onChange={handleChange}
      fullWidth
    >
      {value?.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={item}>
          {item}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};

export default function DataGridTable(props) {
  const { data } = props;
  const files = Object.keys(data);

  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([]);

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "file",
      headerName: "File",
      // width: 200,
      flex: 1,
      renderCell: FileSelect,
    },
    {
      field: "x",
      headerName: "X",
      // width: 200,
      flex: 0.5,
      renderCell: ParameterSelect,
    },
    {
      field: "actions",
      headerName: "Delete",
      type: "actions",
      width: 80,
      getActions: (params) => [
        <GridActionsCellItem
          icon={<DeleteIcon />}
          label="Delete"
          onClick={deleteRow(params.id)}
        />,
      ],
    },
  ];

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newRow = {
      id: rows.length + 1,
      file: files,
      x: [],
    };
    setRows((prevState) => [...prevState, newRow]);
  };

  const deleteRow = React.useCallback(
    (id) => () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setRows((prevRows) => prevRows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
      });
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Add row
      </Button>
      <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
        <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} disableSelectionOnClick />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that I could think to accomplish this is by adding an extra field to the column definition as an "easy" place to store the selected value.

```
...

const FileSelect = (props) => {
  const { value, row } = props;

  const [file, setFile] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFile(event.target.value);
    // Set the value here
    row.selectedFile = event.target.value;
  };

  return (
    <Select id="file-select" value={file} onChange={handleChange} fullWidth>
      {value?.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={item}>
          {item}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};

...

{
   field: "selectedFile",
   hideable: true
},

...
```

Then set the selected value (file) in the `FileSelect` parent value in the `selectedFile` column. Then all that was left to do was to make the `parameters` lookup values available to the `ParameterSelect`. Again, I just stuffed them into the `renderCell` props, but this could be done better as well:

```
...

{
   field: "x",
   headerName: "X",
   flex: 0.5,
   // Passing the entire original data in as an extra param, for demonstration purposes
   renderCell: (props) => ParameterSelect({ ...props, data })
},

...
```

Finally, just hide the `selectedFile` column:

```
...

<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  disableSelectionOnClick
  // Hiding the extra field
  columnVisibilityModel={{
     selectedFile: false
  }}
/>

...
```

Producing this: *(I changed your values to make them easier to read while I was working)*

[image: I think this is what you wanted]

**Working CodeSandBox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-sun-bdvcu0?file=/demo.js:842-854